# Android NDK: specify different cmake arguments for each target

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

There are several native libs in this Android app. One of them ("vulkan_info") will only build with the argument "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24."  However, the other libs need to support minSdkVersion 16.

Using the build.gradle section posted below, the arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE" "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24" apply to all of the targets. Everything works fine on SDK 24+ but not on earlier versions of Android. I would like the "mali_info" and "adreno_info" libraries to work on earlier Android versions.

How do I specify the cmake arguments so they only apply to "vulkan_info" and not to the other targets? Or alternatively, how could I specify different arguments for each target? Maybe I could do this in CMakeLists.txt? I'm using Android Studio

build.gradle

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {              
                targets 'mali_info'      //I don't want the arguments to apply to this
                targets 'adreno_info'    //or this
           
                targets 'vulkan_info'    //the arguments below need to apply to this 

                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24"
            }
}
```

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(
        adreno_info
        SHARED
        src/main/cpp/adreno_info.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
        adreno_info
        log
)

add_library(
        mali_info
        SHARED
        src/main/cpp/mali_info.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
        mali_info
        log
)


add_library(
        vulkan_info
        SHARED
        src/main/cpp/vulkan_info.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
        vulkan_info
        vulkan
        log
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in the scope of one gradle project. You have two options:

1. Split the gradle project into multiple
2. Compile shared libraries outside gradle and add them via `android.sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs`

Comment: That's what I thought.  It's getting tough to support older Android versions, I had been planning to split the project anyways.